# Cluster GeoJSON data with PruneCluster

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, markers

I'm trying to create a cluster with categories using PruneCluster around my GeoJSON layers.

As the example in GitHub They are creating randomly some markers then adding them to the cluster.

I did the same, I got the coords from a GeoJSON layer, stored it in a variable then added it to Prunecluster as follows :

```
leafletView.BuildLeafletClusterIcon = function(cluster) {
        var e = new L.Icon.MarkerCluster();

        e.stats = cluster.stats;
        e.population = cluster.population;
        return e;
    };

    var colors = ['rgb(10, 94, 219)', 'rgb(253, 152, 1)', 'rgb(3, 180, 11)'],
        pi2 = Math.PI * 2;

    L.Icon.MarkerCluster = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            iconSize: new L.Point(44, 44),
            className: 'prunecluster leaflet-markercluster-icon'
        },

        createIcon: function() {
            // based on L.Icon.Canvas from shramov/leaflet-plugins (BSD licence)
            var e = document.createElement('canvas');
            this._setIconStyles(e, 'icon');
            var s = this.options.iconSize;
            e.width = s.x;
            e.height = s.y;
            this.draw(e.getContext('2d'), s.x, s.y);
            return e;
        },

        createShadow: function() {
            return null;
        },

        draw: function(canvas, width, height) {

            var lol = 0;

            var start = 0;
            for (var i = 0, l = colors.length; i < l; ++i) {

                var size = this.stats[i] / this.population;


                if (size > 0) {
                    canvas.beginPath();
                    canvas.moveTo(22, 22);
                    canvas.fillStyle = colors[i];
                    var from = start + 0.14,
                        to = start + size * pi2;

                    if (to < from) {
                        from = start;
                    }
                    canvas.arc(22, 22, 22, from, to);

                    start = start + size * pi2;
                    canvas.lineTo(22, 22);
                    canvas.fill();
                    canvas.closePath();
                }

            }

            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle = 'white';
            canvas.arc(22, 22, 18, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            canvas.fill();
            canvas.closePath();

            canvas.fillStyle = '#555';
            canvas.textAlign = 'center';
            canvas.textBaseline = 'middle';
            canvas.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';

            canvas.fillText(this.population, 22, 22, 40);
        }
    });


let myLayerOptionsArbre = {

        pointToLayer: createCustomIcon,
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.titre);
            layer.on({
                click: onMarkerClick
            });
            coordsArb.push(feature.geometry.coordinates);

        }
    }

var arb = arbres
    var arbre = new L.GeoJSON(arb, myLayerOptionsArbre)

var ap = {}

    for (var i = 0; i < coordsAP.length; i++) {

        ap = new PruneCluster.Marker(coordsAP[i][1], coordsAP[i][0]);
        console.log(typeof ap)
        console.log("hey", coordsAP[i][1])
        ap.category = AIRES_PROTEGEES;
        leafletView.RegisterMarker(ap);
    }

leafletView.ProcessView();
    mymap.addLayer(leafletView)
```

Now on my map I have the clusters around new markers and the GeoJSON layers. When I read the doc, I found that Prunecluster does not support GeoJSON.
Now if I just work with markers, How can I attach them to the properties of the geojson features, because I'm building custom popups with the function `onMarkerClick` called when a geojson feature is clicked.

So if you have an idea about how to achieve that I would be pleased.

Comment: I used your suggestion and it worked. I thought I accepted the answer but forgot. My apologies.

Comment: What you don't like in the way you have done it already, through `onEachFeature` option of GeoJSON layer creation?

Comment: Yes I'm getting the coords from onEachFeature and the clusters are being created but not arround the geojson layers. New markers are created with  ap = new PruneCluster.Marker(coordsAP[i][1], coordsAP[i][0]);, added to map then clustered. Geojson layers overlap the clusters and it's a mess.

Comment: So simply don't add GeoJSON layer to the map.

Comment: I know but how am I supposed to get the properties(fields) of each geojson. The markers have only the coords

Comment: Please edit your question and describe more in detail what you try to achieve. Where/why do you need those properties?  For marker popup? Or just tooltips? You have `createCustomIcon` function. You are probably using to create markers, but those should be created with `PruneCluster` plugin, you cannot mix both.

Comment: @TomazicM Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display markers with `PruneCluster` plugin, you cannot combine that with displaying the same markers through GeoJSON layer.

If your markers are coming from GeoJSON data, you can use Leaflets `L.geoJSON` for iterating through features/points, but markers must be created only with instances of `PruneCluster.Marker` object.

Since markers created with `PruneCluster` plugin are not standard Leaflet markers, you cannot assign popups or event handlers to those markers using standard Leaflet methods. There is solution for this in the form of overriding `PrepareLeafletMarker(leafletMarker, data)` method (see docs at https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/PruneCluster). First parameter `leafletMarker` is standard Leaflet marker to which you can apply all standard marker methods for creating tooltips, popups, event handlers etc. Second parameter is `data`, which contains data from marker's `data` property, supplied at the time of marker creation, for example:

```
var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker(latLng.lat, latLng.lng);
marker.data.properties = feature.properties;
leafletView.RegisterMarker(marker);
```

For marker from the above example, `data.properties` would contain all the feature's properties.

Below is simple example of creating `PruneCluster` markers from GeoJSON source `geojsonData`. Popup is assigned to marker from feature's property `name`, and upon marker click all the feature's properties are displayed in the console.

```
var map = L.map("map", {
  attributionControl: false,
  zoomControl: false
}).setView(new L.LatLng(41.89, 12.49), 15);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  detectRetina: true,
  maxNativeZoom: 17
}).addTo(map);

var leafletView = new PruneClusterForLeaflet();
leafletView.Cluster.Size = 160;

leafletView.PrepareLeafletMarker = function(leafletMarker, data) {
  leafletMarker.bindPopup(data.properties.name);
  leafletMarker.on('click', function(evt){
    console.log(data);
  });
};

L.geoJSON(geojsonData, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latLng) {
    var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker(latLng.lat, latLng.lng);
    marker.data.properties = feature.properties;
    leafletView.RegisterMarker(marker);
  }
});

map.addLayer(leafletView);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked for me.